# properties-maven-plugin: Error loading properties-file

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin

I want to extract all the properties from my pom.xml into a properties-file. These are the common properties like dependency-versions, plugin-versions and directories.
I'm using the properties-maven-plugin, but its not working as i want it to.

The essential part of my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-alpha-1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>initialize</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
       <files>
          <file>${basedir}/pom.properties</file>
        </files>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Now when i run "mvn properties:read-project-properties" i get the following error:

```
[INFO] One or more required plugin parameters are invalid/missing for 'properties:read-project-properties'

[0] Inside the definition for plugin 'properties-maven-plugin' specify the following:

<configuration>
  ...
  <files>VALUE</files>
</configuration>.
```

The pom.properties-file is located in the same dir as the pom.xml.
What can i do to let the properties-maven-plugin read my properties-file?

**EDIT**

I filed an issue at http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MOJO-1523. 
It has been closed as "not a bug", the reason is:

> It's by design. The project definition
>   has to be self-contained, otherwise it
>   is no longer complete if it is refered
>   from elsewhere as part of the
>   transitive deps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT2**

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848742/change-properties-in-pom-xml-at-runtime-with-maven-ant-tasks-is-it-possible) for a workaround using Ant Tasks, which makes this use case possible

Answer (score 6):

Your `configuration` element is defined inside an `execution` and thus applies to this `execution` only.

So either call `mvn initialize` (or a phase posterior to `initialize`) to use the `configuration` of your current `execution` binding.

Or use a global `configuration`:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
    <configuration>
     <files>
        <file>etc/config/dev.properties</file>
      </files>
    </configuration>
    ...
  </plugin>
```

And then call

```
mvn properties:read-project-properties
```

But that wouldn't make much sense in the particular case of this plugin (you want the properties to be available during the build) so this leaves you with the first solution.

---

**Update:** I did a test on my side and, indeed, with the following POM:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>Q2664362</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <files>
                <file>etc/config/dev.properties</file>
              </files>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Running `mvn test` won't work: maven will try to download `junit:jar:${junit.version}` (i.e. it doesn't use the value of the property) and this will obviously fail.

```
$ mvn test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building SO - Q2664362 - maven-properties-plugin demo
[INFO]    task-segment: [test]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [properties:read-project-properties {execution: default}]
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/pascal/Projects/stackoverflow/Q2664362/src/main/resources
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/${junit.version}/junit-${junit.version}.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'junit:junit:pom:${junit.version}' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [resources:testResources {execution: default-testResources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/pascal/Projects/stackoverflow/Q2664362/src/test/resources
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/${junit.version}/junit-${junit.version}.jar
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'junit:junit:jar:${junit.version}' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.
...
```

The odd part is that the download of the dependency occurs after `properties:read-project-properties`. I'm not sure but this sounds like a bug, you should open [an issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MOJO/component/13703).

Comment: Thank you very much, good hint! The error is gone away. 

But what i want to do still doesn't work: the properties in my pom.xml don't get replaced by the ones in my prop-file. E.g. when i call "mvn properties:read-project-properties test" i get errors like 

"Missing:
----------
1) junit:junit:jar:${junit.version}"

Do i have to run any other specific goal so that maven correctly inserts the properties at "runtime"?

Comment: Thank you for your tips. Just filed an issue. As it seems, i'm the only one who needs such a "feature" ;)

Comment: @Wolkenarchitekt you are not the only one :) Where is the issue? I'd like to +1 it.

My understanding is that we'll need to load the properties as the first step of the validate phase. I don't know yet how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Try using validate phase instead of initialize for maven 3.x ([link](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)).

Answer (score -1):

I encounter your question, but i tried to add this resources here, it works well.

```
 <build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/config</directory> //your config folder
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>initialize</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <files>
                    <file>src/config/config.properties</file> //your config file
                  </files>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
            </plugin>
    </build>
Hope you resolve this as above
```