# Change properties in pom.xml at runtime with Maven Ant Tasks. Is it Possible?

Tags: ant, properties, maven, pom.xml

I have the following use case:
My application is started with an Ant Script, which asks the user several questions about the project configuration (database settings etc.). These settings are stored in a properties-file.

Then i want to run Maven from within my Ant script by Maven Ant Tasks, which should replace the pre-defined properties in my pom.xml with the properties of the properties-file.
I don't want to change the pom.xml.

Is there a way to do this?
Thanks in advance!

([BTW i already tried a similar approach with maven only, which seems to be impossible at the moment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664362/properties-maven-plugin-error-loading-properties-file))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can redefine the properties on the maven command line using `-D` and these will override the properties in your project file.

For example, in pom.xml

```
  <properties>
     <myProp>A</myProp>
  </properties>
```

In your ant build.xml, you can then invoke the mvn command line like

```
mvn -DmyProp=B install
```

which Will set myProp to B in the project. The [mvn ant task page](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/examples/mvn.html) discusses using a macro to invoke the maven commandline. This can be easily customized to also pass the additional properties.

To do this in maven alone, use the [exec](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) plugin to launch maven, passing the command parameters in the same way as done using the ant:java task.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to replace the properties on the fly through `<copy>` ant task ?

Assume your properties are in file `settings.properties`. Define the properties to replace in your `pom.xml` with `@` around them, you can copy the pom file and substitute some properties at the same time. E.g.:

```
<copy file='pom.xml' toFile='real-pom.xml'>
  <filterset filtersfile='settings.properties' />
</copy>
```

Then you invoke maven:

> mvn -f real-pom.xml